# MySQL find only those that are not within 24 hours with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say today is 16th of November, 2013

and, let's say I have a table of dates like so

```
------------------------
id | foreign_id | date
------------------------
1  | 1          | 2013-11-01 05:42:38
2  | 2          | 2013-11-04 04:21:22
3  | 2          | 2013-11-16 15:11:55
```

I want to select those entries where there were no records of past 24 hours.

ie: id #3 was today at 15:11, so I don't want to select `foreign_id` that are 2.

I tried following with CakePHP 2.x in it's `find api` conditions

`'HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), Traffic.accessed)) > 24'`

Where Traffic is some table and accessed is some date field.
Unfortunately this still selects this record because it finds that there are previous entries that are having a date that are older than 24 hours.

Please help.

**UPDATE**

My actual query is like this

```
SELECT Traffic.accessed, Traffic.access_ip, Traffic.client_order_id 
FROM `mdb`.`client_orders` AS `ClientOrder`
LEFT JOIN `geclicks`.`traffics`
AS `Traffic` ON (`Traffic`.`client_order_id` = `ClientOrder`.`id`)
WHERE `ClientOrder`.`status` = 'ACTIVE' AND `ClientOrder`.`offer_clicks` = 0 
AND NOT (`ClientOrder`.`offer_id` = 0) AND ((`Traffic`.`access_ip` IS NULL) 
OR (((`Traffic`.`access_ip` <> "444") 
OR (((HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), MAX(`Traffic`.`accessed`))) > 24) 
AND (`Traffic`.`access_ip` = "444")))))) 
GROUP BY `Traffic`.`client_order_id` ORDER BY RAND() ASC
```

Comment: How would you select entries with records that *were* in the past 24 hours?

Comment: `'HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), Traffic.accessed)) < 24'` like this

Comment: I want something like `WHERE HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), max(accessed))) > 24`

Comment: No. You want all records whose foreign_ids don't match your previous response. You can do that with a LEFT JOIN and IS NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select everything:

```
SELECT * FROM Records
```

Now let's filter out bad foreign keys (e.g. 1, 2, and 3):

```
SELECT * FROM Records WHERE foreign_id NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Park that aside... how do we find the `foreign_id`s that have entries within 24 hours:

```
SELECT DISTINCT foreign_id FROM Records WHERE TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), date) <= 24
```

Plug that back in the original instead of the `(1, 2, 3)` example:

```
SELECT * FROM Records WHERE foreign_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT foreign_id FROM Records WHERE TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), date) <= 24)
```

Comment: I don't have a MySQL database with me right now, so if someone could review the `TIMEDIFF` part and correct it, that would be great.

Comment: Yep thanks, This helped me a lot. I mean NOT IN statement. Btw, if anyone will see in CakePHP NOT IN is like this `'NOT' => array('ClientOrder.id' => $ip_visited)` where $ip_visited is a `find->('list',array(..))` result. Thanks @BeemerGuy